# how can i add sleekxmpp openfire message

Tags: python

im trying to add some chat Messages over SleekXMPP and lokal openfire server to a text entry. How can i solve this? i probably tested with var but i didnt work. Maybe i need something like a trigger function that keeps me up to date.

Any Idea?

```
def recieveMessageThread(window):
##threading.Timer(10, recieveMessageThread(vars, window)).start()
con = connectorGet.connectorGet("admin@taisebook-pc", "gilles")
getMsg = con.getMessages()
if not getMsg is None:
    window.set(getMsg)
```